# Can we access Retake image of Default camera

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am new in iOS. I want to know if it is possible to access the retake image button of  `UIImagePickerController`. If so, how do you call a function on that button?

My problem is that I am using `UIImagePickerController` to take an image from the camera and save the image in the documents directory. I have done my task using a `UIImageView` and `UIAlertView` on an other view, but the problem is that I want to save the image before retake image button pressed in camera. What I have to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want using `UIImagePickerController`. Instead, use `AVFoundation` framework for capturing still images in the way you want. Please, check this Apple's sample project http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html.

Comment: @Fahir Thanks! 
please give me some idea about image crop using camera. I mean to say I want to crop image at the time of capturing image user could select image area which they want to crop..... Please help me

Comment: give any link any tutorial like this

Comment: There are plenty of tuts about how to use AVFoundation framework out there. Here is one of them - <http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/ios4-take-photos-with-live-video-preview-using-avfoundation/>. You may search for these things yourself. Good Luck!